# The importance of prayer

Tags: discussion

The site hits public beta soon. We will have many difficult situations after that.

We should remember to pray for this community, for one another and for those passing by. Especially, we should pray for those that cause us the most trouble. And when we are most at each other's throat's, we should remember what Jesus said:

> [**John 13:34-35 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2013:34-35&version=ESV)
>
> A new commandment I give to you, that you love one another: just as I have loved you, you also are to love one another. By this all people will know that you are my disciples, if you have love for one another.

I'll just add that whenever there are two or three people gathered in the name of Jesus, there will be three to four opinions present. But there's also Jesus, and while we might disagree we're still brothers and sisters.

Even though [this site is secular](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians), we are Christians and might actually be of some use here. So let's pray for the will of God to happen.

<sub>I'm sorry if this is a little off-topic even on meta.</sub>

Comment: I'm not going to lie... this made me chuckle a little :)  May the best of feelings be displayed among ALL Christians alike as we share our knowledge of the doctrines of Christ.

Answer (score 6):

[A post referencing 2 Tim 2:23-26](http://www.reddit.com/r/Christianity/comments/jz100/great_passage_for_us_christians_of_rchristianity/) in /r/christianity on reddit seems to apply here.

> 23Again I say, don’t get involved in foolish, ignorant arguments that
>   only start fights. 24A servant of the Lord must not quarrel but must
>   be kind to everyone, be able to teach, and be patient with difficult
>   people. 25Gently instruct those who oppose the truth. Perhaps God will
>   change those people’s hearts, and they will learn the truth. 26Then
>   they will come to their senses and escape from the devil’s trap. For
>   they have been held captive by him to do whatever he wants.

Maybe we could say [The Warrior's Prayer](http://www.turnbacktogod.com/the-warriors-prayer/) as we prepare.

> Heavenly Father,
>   Your Warrior prepares for battle.
>   Today I claim victory over Satan by putting on
>   The whole Armour of God!
>   
>   I put on the Girdle of Truth!
>   May I stand firm in the truth of Your Word
>   So I will not be a victim of Satan’s lies.
>   
>   I put on the Breastplate of Righteousness!
>   May it guard my heart from evil
>   So I will remain pure and holy,
>   Protected under the blood of Jesus Christ.
>   
>   I put on the Shoes of Peace!
>   May I stand firm in the Good News of the Gospel
>   So Your peace will shine through me
>   And be a light to all I encounter.
>   
>   I take the Shield of Faith!
>   May I be ready for Satan’s fiery darts of
>   Doubt, denial and deceit
>   So I will not be vulnerable to spiritual defeat.
>   
>   I put on the Helmet of Salvation!
>   May I keep my mind focused on You
>   So Satan will not have a stronghold on my Thoughts.
>   
>   I take the Sword of the Spirit!
>   May the two-edged sword of Your Word
>   Be ready in my hands
>   So I can expose the tempting words of Satan.
>   
>   By faith your warrior has put on
>   The whole Armour of God!
>   I am prepared to live this day in spiritual victory!
>   
>   Amen