# Why was my question marked as "off-topic"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

I don't really understand why my [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35831/what-is-wrong-with-a-couple-living-together-before-marriage) was marked as "off-topic".
This question was also marked as seeking "pastoral advice." 
Since my post is about some aspect of Christianity (and, thus, is on-topic) and asks for the Baptist position on a current issue (and not what I should do in a particular instance), I do not understand why my question has been closed.  Please help.

Comment: As far as I can see you haven't actually asked for the Baptist view in the question, you have only mentioned something in the comments. You really need to edit that kind of framing info into the question.

Comment: Yes, you need to put all that framing into the actual post.

Comment: `my post is about some aspect of Christianity and asks for the Baptist position` -- No it doesn't. It doesn't mention 'Baptist' anywhere. In a comment you mention Baptists, but you don't make it clear that you're seeking a Baptist answer. You can edit your question to state that if this is your intention.

Answer (score 6):

I closed the question, and wasn't sure which close reason to use.  The question runs afoul of several of the standard close reasons.

- It's ***primarily opinion-based*** in that if you ask several different people, you're likely to get several different opinions

  - You can avoid that by asking for an official doctrinal teaching on the subject, ideally specifying a denomination whose view you want.
- It's a ***Truth*** question, in that it's asking for an explanation on why something is wrong. Based on the wording of the question, you're not asking for a doctrinal view, you're asking for one that is personally convincing to you.

  - You can avoid that by asking for an official doctrinal teaching on the subject, ideally specifying a denomination whose view you want.
- It's ***Too Broad*** for the same reason it's opinion-based.  Several possible reasons can be cited.

  - You can avoid that by asking for an official doctrinal teaching on the subject, ideally specifying a denomination whose view you want.
- I chose the "***Pastoral Advice***" because this is a question asking, again, for something that can be explained in a way that's personally convincing for you.  That's better done by a Pastor that can have a ***dialogue*** with you.  A two-way conversation.  The format of this site doesn't allow for that, it's one question, with answers, but certainly no conversation.

I'm sure the question can be edited in such a way that it can be re-opened, but as it stands, it has multiple issues.

Might I suggest the following Meta posts, to help clarify, and maybe give you ideas on how it can be edited into shape?

- [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines)
- [Pastoral Advice Questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255)
- [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth)
- [According to Whom?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/according-to-whom)
- [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)
- [we're not here to convince you.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-should-we-address-convince-me-questions)
- [On-topic and constructive examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples)
- [Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)