# Am I actually about to be question banned?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, banning

So I clicked on the 'ask' button today (on the main site) and got a warning popup:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

When I check my question history, I appear to have asked only two questions, one rated +6 and one rated +10.  I did post another question recently which was apparently off topic or something so I deleted it, but it only got to (I think) -2 before I did that.  I don't think I've asked any other questions on this site.

I'm still learning what's acceptable here (like most SEs the site guidelines/help center posts aren't what actually describes how to ask/answer questions, various meta posts are) and I think any question I ask probably has about a 40-50% chance of being rejected.

I'm particularly worried about this because I wasn't seeing the before and I just [put a 100 rep bounty on a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35311/what-issues-do-catholics-representing-god-in-fiction-historically-face) and I'm wondering if the site now thinks I just took 100 points of negative question rep.  The question I deleted was after that, though.

Am I actually that close to a question ban and, if so, what should I do about it?

Comment: This came up recently and I answered then. [What causes someone to be question banned?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4201)

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch I was mostly worried about the bounty part of this; I must not have realized how downvoted my other question got before it was deleted.  Hence the bug tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible.  Your history also shows two down-voted deleted questions.  Those factor in as well, so right now you're running about 50/50.  The bounty didn't affect you. That doesn't factor into the calculations.  Just focus on asking questions within the site's guidelines and you should be fine.

All of the following should be helpful...  Probably it's not necessary to read them all, but they're the best Meta posts we have on asking good questions.

- [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines)
- [Pastoral Advice Questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255)
- [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth)
- [According to Whom?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/according-to-whom)
- [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)
- [we're not here to convince you.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-should-we-address-convince-me-questions)
- [On-topic and constructive examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples)
- [Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)

Comment: Glad you could confirm the bounty wasn't involved, that was my major concern.