# My question, posted yesterday, had 1 request to reopen it, has disappeared completely, especially from my folders?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

In the explanation given to me with stack exchange info., it says that questions, even if they get closed, will always remain visible for the person who asked them. No so, mine disappeared.

The question was only asked yesterday, I had just reworded it to fit, and today it is disappeared completely, which is against what the rules say.

As well, it had 1 request to be re-opened.

Also unusual, it said it had a link to a similar question, which it did not, when I clicked the link, it went to another page with no questions on it.

?

Answer (score 7):

It was off-topic (opinion-based), and not likely to be salvageable.  Even after the edit, it was begging for opinion.  It was deleted as many such questions are.

If you want your questions to remain on the site, you need to ask questions that are on-topic.  Here are some links to help you figure out how to do that.  I recommend reading them instead of ignoring them, and actually trying to post questions that are on-topic.

- [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines)
- [Pastoral Advice Questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255)
- [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth)
- [According to Whom?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/according-to-whom)
- [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)
- [we're not here to convince you.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-should-we-address-convince-me-questions)
- [On-topic and constructive examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples)
- [Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)

Comment: The opinion-based part of the whole scenario I described above, is actually in the opinion of the moderator who closed the question. I had proof from both Quran text and Bible text to clearly show each book was speaking about a different person, not the same person, according to writings from each book. I think the moderator made an opinion-based choice, without textual back-up when he 'called' the question 'opinion -based', when the answer can be proven from the core spiritual books of both parties that the question addressed.

Comment: Additionally, each time a different question is asked, it exposes new and different facets as to how it will be perceived, allowed, answered, voted, etc. There really is no set rule, as I have shown above, it was the 'opinion' of the moderator, that the question and answer were 'opinion based', even thought there was textual proof, still not brought forward because the question was scrapped and erased before anyone had a chance to read it let alone answer it. There  is text from the Bible and the Quran that is factual and proveable regarding the question and answer we are discussing.

Comment: Ps  the question was reworded within the same day it was posted, to fit with the comments made. I think you could have given it a chance.