# I don't understand why I cannot answer this question

Tags: discussion, questions, protected

[Why did Jesus say he came to create division?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20164/why-did-jesus-say-he-came-to-create-division)

It seems like this topic was closed because the mods didn't like the comments on it. That seems wrong. Why can't I answer this question? What is going on here?

Comment: That question isn't closed. You need only 10 reputation points to answer it: two up votes on a question or one on an answer. I really don't understand at all why you seem so angry.

Comment: This should be posted on [meta], but OP doesn't have enough rep to participate on meta.

Comment: So, you've left the faith because you can't figure out the site's functions? Yeah, that's reasonable. The question is protected because it has apparently received a bunch of spam in the past. Leave the faith for reason, if that's where it leads you, but this looks more like a rage quit to me.

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to the site. Based on this question, it's apparent that you've completely misunderstood the basic purpose of Christianity.StackExchange.com.  We have strict guidelines in place to prevent EXACTLY the type of thing you're complaining about.

As you're a new visitor, I'd like to recommend the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes":

- [The Tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [The Help](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)

That question isn't closed, it's been protected.  That means that brand new users can't answer.  Most new users DO mistake this site for a discussion forum, where personal understanding is an acceptable answer.

***On this site we don't do personal interpretation.  This site is intended to focus solely on what he various group within Christianity teach, not what is True.***

Questions like the one you cited tend to draw answers about what's "True".  Newcomers who haven't had a chance to learn the ropes tend to post answers that argue over which doctrine is correct, rather than what doctrines are taught.

That then leads to discussion and arguments over who's right.  You can get that at ***any*** Christian discussion forum.  Or any discussion forum in general.  The bottom line is that StackExchange sites are intended to be an alternative to discussion forums as described in the [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

The challenge this site faces is that it's extremely difficult to get people NOT to argue over correct doctrine.

- First, there's a pretty wide variety of doctrines that fall under the umbrella of Christianity.
- Second, most of us believe that knowing the right doctrine has serious eternal consequences to the individual.

That second point is the one that gets us all riled up.  None of us want's to see doctrines that we believe are false being touted as True.  None of us wants to see people being led astray.  That's one reason we stress that this site is ***not** about what's True".  We aren't allowed to post that other views are wrong, but yet at the same time we're not allowed to tout our own beliefs as True.  We simply answer the question asked.  That's explained in [Another reason this is not a Christian site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/another-reason-this-is-not-a-christian-site)

The bottom line is that if you're here at all to discuss eternal Truth, to evangelize, etc, then this isn't the site for you.

Personally, I stuck with this site because it allows me to learn about what others teach, so that I can be prepared for it when I'm talking to people and witnessing in person.  It's easier to counter false doctrine when you understand the false doctrine.

At any rate, if you do decide to participate, and get past those posts, here are some more that drive the guidelines home:

- [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines)
- [Pastoral Advice Questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255)
- [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth)
- [According to Whom?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/according-to-whom)
- [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)
- [we're not here to convince you.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-should-we-address-convince-me-questions)
- [On-topic and constructive examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples)
- [Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)

However, if you do decide you want to participate, your tone will need to change.  Again, this isn't a discussion forum, and rants don't count as questions or answers here.