# Why was this question put on hold as too broad? (Sinful by birth or made sinful by the world?)

Tags: discussion, scope

In Romans 5 we are plainly told in verse 19 it is through one man by birth...I would support it a bit more ...but its is a simple answer it would seem compaired to other questions I have seen on here so far.

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25913/sinful-by-birth-or-made-sinful-by-the-world

Comment: You should [edit] a link to the question you are referencing so we can actually examine it.

Comment: Before you get too frustrated, please see: [Newcomers: Be patient. You will get there if you follow our direction. Keep trying](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1927) and [Types of questions, or template questions, that the community generally finds acceptable](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409)

Comment: @fredsbend, Im not frustrated  I was just curious. Why would I be frustrated???

Comment: @rob A lot of new users do. Just covering the bases.

Comment: @fredsbend,oh I see...mmmm...why get frustrated its just a fourm...its small stuff...hahaha...

Answer (score 1):

Judging only from the title it sounds like it was a truth question, which is [something we don't do](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1380/30) around here. Your answer may seem simple enough to you but with it you are representing what you think in *the truth*, not some aspect of Christianity as a religious entity. Questions that are not about Christianity –and instead are about the spiritual issues that Christianity is about– are often closed (as often as we spot them).

Comment: I added the link at your suggestion and am doing here also.      http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25913/sinful-by-birth-or-made-sinful-by-the-world

Comment: so this is a more what does it say fourm as opposed to what dose it mean.

Comment: @rob This is not a forum at all. There is a strict question and answer format. Q and A site is the best term. We have guidelines on what makes good questions and answers. They can be generally summed up as "it is about Christianity, the religion, not Christianity, the faith." The types of questions link I gave earlier should help the most with this.

Comment: @fredsbend,  actually.... Stack Exchange  fits the definition of forum perfect... fo·rum noun \ˈfor-əm\

: a meeting at which a subject can be discussed

: a place or opportunity for discussing a subject                                      www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forum

Comment: @rob That's exactly our point: forums are for discussion. **We don't do discussion!** We do QnA with a fixed format specifically to avoid as much discussion as possible.

Comment: @Caleb, still fits.... dis·cuss transitive verb \di-ˈskəs\  : to talk about (something) with another person or group  : to give information, ideas, opinions, etc., about (something) in writing or speech          http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discuss

Comment: @rob Despite any dictionary definition you have there, I think the gist of the site is clear. If you want to discuss stuff, hit the chatrooms. About 15 of us are active there daily. You'll find someone to talk to.

Comment: @fredsbend in Christanity and Biblical Hermeneutics with between  33000 and 44000 Christian denominations in the world differing vastly to slightly theologically how does Stack deside what is the "answer" and what is "discussion". As even the posting of facts is discussion.

Comment: @rob [The types of questions meta post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) I showed you covers what the community finds acceptable. Answers to those kinds of questions are pretty obviously right or not right.

Comment: Sometimes there is a starkly different opinion that the rest of us are unaware of. In those cases, the best answer there should update to cover that as well. Optionally and usually what happens is that the person who knows the opposing view posts his own answer. No doubt, it is a difficult task to keep things here factual, but we do the best we can, and I think that's been pretty good so far.

Comment: @fredsbend,ok, Im learning, basically denominational and docternal majority agreeances is the type of questions and answers are the type of ideas and information that you want on this "site". When a question or answer is to broad or does not hold denominational founding, perhaps with to many answers or ideas then it is deemed in apropreate, howm I doin? I like this though you said at the end " Also, remember that everything about Christianity is somebody's opinion." That is about the only truth haha.So its like i kinda wrote at first "what does it say as opposed to what dose it mean."

Comment: @rob Yeah. You got it. And if you get a down vote here or there along the way just brush it off. It happens. If you get some constructive negative feedback, see if there is something you can learn from it, then try to apply it in the future.

Comment: @fredsbend, thx for taking the time I apreciate it!!! Im not on here for votes so neg or pos matters little...Im here, well by accedent at first haha, but now to help if I can and to learn. And I dont mind negative feedback as long as it is CONSTRUCTIVE and not CRITISISING. Underdtand my diffrence??? I know what I know but am open to have my knowledge adjusted. But I like clarity and I tend to be a stickler for semantics (as im sure you can tell) and proper understanding for me comes with proper underdtanding of definitions so I know Im speaking the same language.Make sense?? Thx to Caleb also

Comment: @fredsbend, sorry should of been spelled "criticizing"...

Comment: @fredsbend, I just need to clarify something, does each group get to deside what it is??? Cause Biblical hermeneutics cause their group a fourm.

Comment: @rob I guess, essentially. At its core, every SE site is run by the community. Some of them are very discussion forum style. The English site is kind of there. The Code Golf site is surely there. I don't know how they are on the Hermeneutics site, but I would bet they are pretty strict on factual answers backed up with sources.

Comment: @fredsbend, ok thx...oh and I guess it should of been " calls " and not "cause " wutta typo...I guess just by what Ive always understood the definition 2b,well all the sights here fit that definition, but I guess sometimes ducks wanna be called sumpin else.Haha...thx again for the help  (0:

Answer (score 0):

I think the question deals with the concept of original sin, which may be covered already, since that is a *very popular* topic among Western Christians. You may want to look into the origin, history, and evolution of original sin, and if you are not clear on any theological concepts, you may ask here. Consider this Stack Exchange a Question-and-Answer website for experts, by experts.

Comment: It wasnt my question, I was wanting to post an  answer and couldnt. So this doent help except for the part about it possibly being asked b4.

Comment: Im curious ....who desides "experts"??? And what is this Stack Exchanges definition of an expert??? Because its obvious that the given dictionary definitions are not nesassaraly adhered to. Ive learned in 3 days here just cause it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck does not make it a duck on this Stack Exchange.

Comment: @rob People who know stuff and study this stuff. Biblical scholars, classical historians, theologians, priests, pastors, rabbis.

Comment: thats doesnt answer my question. Does Stack have a page with these "experts" listed? "People who know" is very very vauge.You didnt answer who dedides or what the definition that Stack considers experts. Unless the general titles in the second sentece are the "Who" and if thats so is there a place to actually verify these folks are experts.

Comment: I mean,  Im a minister that has studied for 40 years and still would not say Im an expert. Hahaha.

Comment: The purpose is to generate accurate information for each question. As long as you do that, expert or not, you are contributing to the Stack Exchange constructively.

Comment: I would say after reading Caleb and Fredsdend the most popular information for each question. And thats not always the most accurate.  But thanks anyhow for making an attempt to answer this question. I apreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I asked that question but it seems it is not suited for Christianity.SE. I asked again in Hermeneutics.SE. You may try to answer it there.

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/sinful-by-birth-or-made-sinful-by-the-world

Comment: Very good thanks for the tip and as you will see I did go answer. I hope it helped and brought some clairity. Though I know not all will agree.

Comment: seems hermeneutics wasnt proper either huh??? I wouldnt of conciderd the question to fall under systematic theology, anyhow did you get to read the response? Takes me a while to type and think not to mention get facts together...kinda disapointed me my hard work was cast off...haha...anyhow if there is a way to contact me (Im new as you know) do so and I will send you the answer. My best to u n urs.

Comment: @rob I think I should start a new StackExchange site where anyone can ask whatever they want about the Bible and Theology. You with me? :)

Comment: hahaha...well if you build it I will come...haha...I am having a bit of a problem adjusting to this format, as you know if you read my other comments on this thread,  but i'll adjust. I have a few questions of my own that I would like to ask but I'm afraid they will get shot down also as to broad. So yeah I would support your page as well. Is it hard to build  one here??? Perhaps you should pull me into chat to talk further on this. I would but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @rob It's a long process and I don't think I have time to do such things. :) It is done in http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wow...over 500 proposals ...well I can understand time constraints,  to bad though. Well I hope you find your answer, if there is a way I would have no problem sending you what I posted if you didnt get to read it. If you find it acceptable I think it would bring you not only some peace but perhaps hope. (o: