# Unfair downvoting and judgement of my answers

Tags: discussion, scope

At first I thought this was happening, but wasn't totally sure if it was just random, or not.

I am now completely sure that there is some definite unfairness in downvoting and now, deleting my posted answer.

Case in point on downvoting, right here minus nine on meta discussion, really  you must downvote on discussions? Take a break.

This just is not ok and not what this site should be about, if it is what you say it is.

Comment: @Flimzy-what did you edit in my post here?

Comment: @DavidStratton - below -wrong -not opinions

Comment: @All - I did not provide any example with my post here, I think Flimzy must have and then maybe erased it.  I did find identical content to some posts of mine in other older posts on your site, and they received upvotes for their posts with content and I received downvotes on same content and many downvotes,- I assume this is just random according to preferences of who happens to be online and come along,- correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `Flimzy must have [provided an example] and then maybe erased it` - his edit was only to the tags.  Instead of repeatedly claiming they exist, you need to edit your question to include some links to older posts that are "identical" to posts of yours.

Comment: @Ward -Flimzy made an edit, and another comment mentioned the example I gave, but I didn't give an example, and I don't see what Flimzy edited, since it looks same to me

Comment: @all - ok, even on Meta when you want to discuss, Still DOWNVOTES! on discussion!- whew! couldn't you take a break from that, to even discuss things? -9 downvotes? really?

Comment: Multiple people (me, for one) have suggested you spend some time learning how things work on SE...  For example, from the menu at the top of the page that says "Help," choose the item "What's Meta?" and read the second section about what votes here on meta mean.

Comment: @Ward how do I link posts?

Comment: To link to a question, copy its URL and then when editing your post, click the Hyperlink icon - looks like a chain.

Comment: Re Flimzy's edit, you can see exactly what is done to a post and when through it's **edit history**  the link to the left of user id box at the bottom of the post in the form "edited XXXXX ago".

Comment: @Hello Links are done like this: `[link](http://example.com)`, which results in this: [link](http://example.com).

Answer (score 11):

the problem is that you are simply not operating within site guidelines.  You ask questions that beg for opinion, and your answers give your opinions.

Moderators and other users alike have attempted several times to explain this to you, and point you to the various Meta posts that try to explain the site guidelines, and either you are simply not getting it, or you are flat out refusing to get it.

The bottom line is your content is voted down, closed, and deleted simply because it is not appropriate to this site.  It would be perfectly fine on an discussion forum, or your own personal blog, but not here.

One more time, one more Meta posts, I suggest reading this:

[What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt)

Your posts consistently fall within the "what it isn't" category.  As long as your posts continue to fall into that category, they will continue to be down-voted, closed, deleted, etc.  that's not "unfair" it's "Applying the site guidelines consistently".

Comment: funny, but I found the EXACT content of my posts in older posts that received multiple UPvotes. Therefore this proves that my content IS in keeping with the site, since it received Many upvotes when it appeared previously written by others in similar question and answers.

Comment: therefore Content is not the main issue at all

Comment: @Hello  Prove it. Give us examples.

Comment: is this just a kind of common thing, up or downvotes are random people reading and voting, and doing so according to their own opinions and biases, so votes are just whoever happens along to read and express what they think and they might not even read the question fully or even know what is behind the question anyway,..

Comment: here is an example of something,- - - someone made some comments on one of mine that would be in keeping with a very liberal type, yet when they chatted they presented themselves as a very committed conservative Christian, totally opposite from the comments on my question; ? I read their chat to someone else while waiting for them in a room  -

Comment: @Hello That's not a real example. Links or it didn't happen. You need to give a link of one of your posts, then give a link of another that is not yours but is similar enough that they should be treated the same way. Then you need to do that multiple times before we will be convinced something other than your post quality is to blame.

Comment: There are always a few around that don't get it, and they tend to vote up others with Truthy content. Even if you do get some up votes, that does not validate the idea that your posts are on topic. The mist vile racist can get high fives from other racists. I'm not saying you're a racist by the way, but using that as an analogy to say that just because a few people agree does not make your actions right.

Comment: @DavidStratton Are you referring to the logical fallacy of appealing to the *minority*? Though still a fallacy, I'm not sure how effect it is.

Comment: @DavidStratton- re your "on topic"-  asking a question is not an 'on topic' reason for my question to be put 'on hold' and especially not for it to be 'deleted'. Other questions ie. "what is the Biblical definition of marriage" and the answer and what happened to that question is an example of some of the strange things done to questions here.