# I am not Christian, but can I still contribute to the blog, assuming a Christian perspective?

Tags: discussion, blog

I am not Christian, but can I still contribute to the blog, assuming a Christian perspective? Suppose one day I assume a Catholic perspective, pretending I am a bona fide Catholic, wholeheartedly supporting ***all*** the doctrines of the Catholic church and the Pope, because he's ***awesome***. Can I submit my blog entry for review and ask the reviewer(s) whether the blog post is Catholic enough?

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure [being a Christian](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/30) or subscribing to a specific creed had never been our qualification for anything around here. That being said, I'm pretty sure most of the folks around here would be uncomfortable with what you are proposing. Pretending to be something you are not is a recipe for failure.

Instead I propose something else. Be yourself. Figure out what you believe and why. Be whatever that makes you. As for writing for the blog, participants are expected to represent an identifiable position that they know well. There is no particular reason you have to be a Catholic in order to represent their position well, but in practice this sort of abstraction is *very* difficult even for the most knowledge and skillful writers to do.

I would be happy to see the blog cranked up again as I think it was a great outlet, but that will take more than one author stepping up to the plate. If that happens and you want to participate we can certainly evaluate your idea for a specific post and whether it fits the blog's motif. I suggest this is more likely to happen if you don't try to put on a face that doesn't align with where your heart is.

Comment: I see there is no Lutheran perspective. Maybe I can write an article about Lutheranism in third-person persona. The blog motif seems to carry a very informative, encyclopedic tone.

Comment: Elberich Schneider(spelling?) is a member on the Stack Exchange Network, esp. this one. He says that he belongs to the Roman Catholic denomination but takes an Adoptionist viewpoint, which according to Dr. R.C. Sproul, would be considered heresy. Still, can I write for him, assuming the viewpoint of an adoptionist Catholic, or are the entries all supposed to be orthodox and traditional?

Comment: @Anonymous The blog is not moderated to limit its theological breadth. Just like this site it's scope is Christianity _and all it's associated heresies_. The issue with the blog is that we do expect a significant level of subject matter expertise and for posts to be a good reflection of whatever view they claim to represent. Are you and expert in Adoptionism? Are you an expert in Lutheranism? Are the intricacies of those systems familiar to you? (Side note: Elberich has actually claimed this site helped him determine that he isn't actually a Catholic)

Comment: I'd do some reading then. It is universally acknowledged that good writing is correlated with a lot of reading. Reading an entire volume of books about Lutheranism and some published diary entries about the Lutheran life, as well as narrowing the scope to a particular church group under Lutheranism, might do the trick. This is going to take a while...

Comment: I had to look twice at "[wound up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wind-something-up?q=wind+something+up)".

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hmm. That link has exactly the opposite usage than I intended. I'll use one that is less ambiguous.

Comment: @Caleb third definition would be what you were getting at I think? Though cranked probably *does* work better

Comment: @waxeagle Yes #3 was what I was going for, but the fact that that Andrew was looking it up in the first place and the first two definitions were the opposite of what I wanted to say...