# Is this a Catholic site?

Tags: discussion, catholicism

The questions on  SE Christianity sometimes seem Catholic oriented. Is this a Catholic site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18642/discussion-between-hello-and-fms).

Comment: Questions about the site itself should be asked here on meta (I've migrated your question. That being said it looks like you could benefit from a look around at some of the posts tagged [meta-tag:faq] here.

Comment: Related: [Are we ready for Catholicism.SE?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3884)

Comment: @Caleb, no, then P's and C's wouldn't be mixing, and you will argue amoungst yourselves only. :) this way, we can be exposed to the 'other' beliefs, which should have an upside...

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not a Catholic site. We do have a lot of active Catholic users. Catholcism is also a very large group and demographically they make up a large chunk of the world's "Christians". It's only natural that we would see a lot of qusetions in their scope.

On the other hand this sit is NOT limited to any particular theological tradition. Not only are there other branches of Christianity that can be asked about, but the beliefs of divergant sects, cults and all Christian heresies is also in-scope here. It is expected that questions about any specific belief structure be answered from the perspective of the group being questioned.

- If you ask questions about Catholics, expect to get the Catholic perspective.
- If you ask questions about Mormons, expect to get the Mormon perspective.
- If you ask questions about Reformed Protestants, expect to get the Reformed Protestand perspective.
- If you ask questions about Gnostics, expect to get a Gnostic perspective.

Officically this site is run by a non-Christian company and the site itself does not endorse any particular creed. See also [Brothers, we are not Christians‼](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/30)

Comment: not run by Christians, maybe by extremist M.'s finding out everything to bother us with later...or maybe the future world ruling group that will come against us?

Comment: to sum up, for ie. then, if I asked questions regarding the Pope and whether or not He went against expressed Bible teachings with his words - only a Catholic could answer because the Pope is Catholic?, and if they -the one answering edited my question to make it easier-sounding to Catholic ears would I have to allow this, or could I edit the question back and put it bk into wording that expressed great concern over things said and done?

Comment: can you only answer if you are part of the group the question is directed toward?

Comment: according to your answer above, never a Protestant answer is valid to a question about Catholic topics, ? then, for example, ?

Comment: 'the man of sin, and or son of perdition' and his group may be future users of this info, against us,...possibly...

Comment: someone edited my questions and reworded them because they said I would get a downvote, yet they answered the question and I did not know enough about how things work to know if I should or have to allow it,..and it also somewhat changed the direction of the question, as well he and I are on opposing opinion sides of the thrust of the question, ie Prot. and Cath. sides,..so...a Catholic gets to answer from the Cath side,...explaining, but I can still challenge the answer, but I can't answer if they have explained and justified from their own writings,...-right?

Comment: @Hello You need to slow down for a second and do some reading up about the site because you are making a bunch of assumptions that are not the case. Your example scenario questions that you cannot even ask at all because they are "truth" questions. Please read: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1380)

Comment: @C yes I saw the truth questions pointed out somewhere, I will read it,...

Comment: @Hello - it is worth adding that you don't have to be part of a group to answer a question directed at them, but you do have to answer from their perspective.  It's best to think of this as more of an academic site, like a university religious studies class.  We're here to discuss what the views are of any group of people that call themselves Christian, not to discuss which views are correct.  If you ask or answer a question in a way that seems to indicate that one view is correct and another false, it is likely going to be edited or deleted as that isn't the point of the site.

Comment: @AJ thankyou, I noted to that it is possible for downvotes to be used wrongly, with no  repercussion for anyone who does it,-correct?

Comment: @Hello - yes, there is no way to stop someone from upvoting answers they agree with as true and downvoting ones they disagree with as false since people don't have to explain their reason for voting on things, but there are some other safeguards that help protect against voting patterns that look invalid.

Comment: @ALL thank you so much, I did have some wrong ideas about how it worked,...AJ above -that explains what some people were doing jumping in on my question- I got defensive, but wasn't sure what to do about it,..that is why the way my questions were worded were changed, even by the guy answering,....

Comment: OK did this site come upon this method that allows those from opposing groups and views to drop their opposition and operate just as brothers and sisters, accidentally? If you think about it, the site rules free up the usual -which pov and doctrine is correct arguments, then,..which equals PURE GENIUS! thankyou so much!!!

Comment: I can't guarantee that I can stick to the parameters until I've used them for awhile....and get a handle on it...

Comment: SOME GENIUS took arguing pov's right out of the equation, either inadvertently or deliberately,...by the rules of this site,  freeing us up to brotherhood, it would seem

Comment: @Hello [Brothers, we are not Christians‼](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/193)

Comment: @Hello No. Empatically no. It is not genious and it does not solve the problems facing the church. It does not even allow them to be opened! It is not genius. It may be a good thing and may serve a particular purpose but in no way can it or should it replace the church, and only the church is in a position to overcome its own issues. This is a purely secular veture by some Christians and some others into a public square. Even those of us who have most embrased it most empatically reject that it is in any way an anecdote for inter-church or inter-tradition issues.

Comment: @Caleb- when do you sleep? I just woke up so thought I'd drop in

Comment: @Hello It's currently just mid-day where I live. Also comments are not a chat room, lets please keep them for limited discussion of the issue at hand and leave the chatter that would not be relevant to others reviewing the topic later to the actual chat room. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say "a lot of active Catholic users". I think there might be 10 or 15 that I can remember conversing with over the life of the site.  Its the only tag I get emails on so I think I've read ever Catholicism tagged post.