# Migrated from Christianity.SE

Tags: discussion

When migrating from Christianity.SE to hermeneutics, we have the following text

> This question came from our site for committed Christians, experts in
>   Christianity and those interested in learning more.

as seen [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/why-does-the-bible-say-that-abraham-sacrificed-his-only-begotten-son)

Does this fly in the face of [Brothers, we are not Christians‼](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians)

Maybe something like this is more appropriate?

> This question came from our site about Christians denominations; their beliefs and practices.

Comment: It's not saying everyone here is a Christian or an expert in Christianity, and denominations are only one part of the site. And I think it's copied from the [tour] page, so that would need to be changed. Which might be worth doing.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it "flies in the face" of that meta post, but I could see where it could be misleading. Your alternative might be a step in the right direction, but what about this:

> This question came from our site for the study of Christianity and its denominations, history, beliefs, and practices.

Answer (score -3):

Either of the two above suggestions are an improvement, but in reality the site does not foster study, it is only a question and answer prevue and as it advertises not all posters are Christian. perhaps that thought might need be more illuminated.

Comment: Why does the fact that it's a question and answer site mean it doesn't foster study?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude  There is a difference between inspiring and fostering. Answers are straight forward and they can inspire one to study, but does not necessarily create study of the subject.