# Is Sola Scriptura a violation of the rules when asking or answering a question about the bible?

Tags: discussion

I had a question deleting without any reason given.  I've asked but still have not heard a reason by the 5 people who voted against it, including **Ken Graham**, a mod here.

[According to Trinitarians, what are God's hands, feet, face, and mouth?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/93091/60347)

I believe the reason this question was voted to be closed is because of the answer to this question.  Perhaps these 5 individuals did not like that their only answer is "There exists ZERO scriptural support for this trinitarian claim."

---

Then we have this question by another user who also **only asks for scriptural support**:

[What is the biblical basis for the belief that good works are the fruits of faith?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/51004/60347)

Now I know he only wants scriptural support because he asks another question later:

[Where did the formula, "Good works are the fruits of faith," originate?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55709/where-did-the-formula-good-works-are-the-fruits-of-faith-originate)

I answered both the same because my answer sufficiently qualifies under the premise of each question.

Here is my answer:
[What is the biblical basis for the belief that good works are the fruits of faith?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/93182/25495)

My answer to the later question was unilaterally deleted by **Mason**, a different mod.

The later question was also the one with the bounty so I had to answer it and explain that the premise is faulty by using Jesus' words....which is always a good way to answer.

**Peter Turner**, a 3rd mod, has also deleted this answer of mine:
[From a non-trinitarian perspective, how is love explained as an attribute of God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/93372/60347)

Here is why:
*"I deleted this post because you reverted an edit twice that did not change the content of the post, please allow other members of the community to help you so you can become a productive member of the community. Do not revert edits, we're all in this together. –
Peter Turner ♦"*

**He stated in the comments of the now deleted answer that citing the apostles, James and Paul is not sufficient for an answer.**  This comment spawned its own meta question by another user here which has since been ignored...
[Are thousands of answers now in jeopardy?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7354/60347)

This is getting kinda absurd no?  He had no good cause to edit my answer.

He must really dislike my answer to the point that he is willing to set new precedents for what qualifies an answer.   Answers that do not comply can be unilaterally deleted.  My answer was well stated and supported ideas counter to this single mod's ideas by using scripture ONLY.  So he deleted it....

But really Peter is NOT trying to set a new precedent. He is simply creating a TEMPORARY rule to delete my words which only cite the bible. This rule will NOT be used to decide on any other answer or question.  And all those who agree with Peter's ideas will be silent about this.

---

***Is it a rule that a question CAN NOT ONLY ask for scriptural support?***  The mods are acting this way towards my words here.

***If its not a rule, why is my question closed?***  I was about to offer a bounty.

I've had 2 answers unilaterally deleted by mods which only use biblical citations.
***Is it a rule that answers are not sufficient which only use scriptural support?***

Answer (score 3):

Answering this question is just a catch-22.

If we answer yes, then you can ask any question

> "Why do birds suddenly appear, every time you are near, according to the Bible?"

If we answer no, then you can't ask

> "What is the scriptural support for the doctrine of the Trinity"

but, I'll offer a *distinguo* and this is the entire ethos of Christianity StackExchange, and if someone wants to write a doctoral dissertation about what we're doing here, go for it and send it to the Pope and CC me, for I think we've solved all interdenominational conflict.

The question about the Trinity, assumes the doctrine of the Trinity (which is a Christian doctrine whether you accept it or not).  The question about Birds assumes Birds suddenly appear (which is not a Christian doctrine)

So you need to consider the implicit doctrine in the question when ASKING and the implicit doctrine when ANSWERING anything else should be flagged/closed/deleted.

Comment: I am considering the doctrine. Its this doctrine of the triune god that asserts unbiblical ideas regarding His body He describes.  Why would I send it to the Pope?  Is he in charge?  BTW the trinity is only a Christian doctrine by those who have co-opted the name Christian from those in Antioch who actually were followers of Christ.

Comment: You need to assume the doctrine is true to answer the question

Comment: Is that another rule that doesn't exist?  Which btw... a doctrine is by nature UNTRUE if it can not be found anywhere in scripture.

Comment: No, that rule definitely exists, everyone who has engaged with you knows this rule and has been trying to tell you it

Comment: What is the rule exactly?  No one would answer a question about a doctrine if they did not believe it to be true....

Comment: Is James and Paul not good enough support for my answers? @PeterTurner

Comment: It's perfectly OK to answer a question about a doctrine you don't believe to be true. What is not OK is to deny the premise of any question, it doesn't matter if you're quoting James or Paul  (George or Ringo for that matter). If you're denying the premise of the question, you are not posting an answer.

Comment: Actually no... Denying the premise by explaining how it is false is one of the best ways to answer a question.  Like my 1+1+1=1 question; this premise was bulletproof and was unable to be denied logically so you unilaterally deleted it.  If one were able to deny the premise many would have....

Answer (score 2):

**Is *Sola Scriptura* a violation of the rules when asking or answering a question about the bible?**

The short answer is **no**.

But your question, [According to Trinitarians, what are God's hands, feet, face, and mouth?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/93091/according-to-trinitarians-what-are-gods-hands-feet-face-and-mouth) has to imply more than simply a ***Sola Scriptura*** response. Doctrines and beliefs must be given and scholarly research explains Scriptures through interpretation and biblical hermeneutics.

The vast majority of Trinitarians simply do not adhere to a ***Sola Scriptura*** mentality.

As a side note: Not all who voted to close your question were Trinitarians!!!

Notwithstanding all this I would not answer your question, not because there is **zero** Scriptural support for a Trinitarian claim as you suggest, but rather I can see a question phrased in such a way as to lead to endless picking in the comments. Thus I would naturally abstain from answering such a question.

In the future could please fact check your questions on meta. Some of your statements are incorrect.