# BLOCK QUESTIONS/ANSWERS/COMMENTS THAT ARE WRITTEN IN ALL CAPS

Tags: discussion, feature-request

RECENTLY ON [THIS QUESTION](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/74156/why-do-pastors-promote-false-teachings) I FOUND A RUDE COMMENT THAT WAS WRITTEN IN ALL CAPS.  I WAS VERY OFFENDED AND I FLAGGED IT AS **UNFRIENDLY OR UNKIND**.  THE COMMENT FLAG WAS MARKED AS **HELPFUL** (GOOD COMMENT FLAGS ARE MARKED **HELPFUL**; NEUTRAL FLAGS AS WELL AS BAD ONES ARE MARKED **DECLINED**), AND THE COMMENT WAS IMMEDIATELY DELETED.  NOW I SEE THAT THE WHOLE QUESTION IS DELETED, TOO.

THIS SITE IS FOR VERY RELIGIOUS CHRISTIANS.  ANY "NOISE" WILL RUIN THIS WHOLE SITE AND IS VERY IRRITATING ME.  I AM ALSO A CHRISTIAN.

CAN WE PLEASE BLOCK ANY QUESTIONS/ANSWERS/COMMENTS HERE THAT ARE WRITTEN IN ALL CAPS?

> WARNING: This question is written as exactly how it is supposed to look, **as an example of a post that is written in all-capitals.**  Please do not change the capitalization.

Comment: There might be some algorithm that bubbles these kinds of posts into the review queue.  But this was a request on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps) a few years ago if you want to check out the discussion there

Comment: `ANY "NOISE" WILL RUIN THIS WHOLE SITE` - Your explanation of flags isn't relevant to what you're requesting, nor are your comments about how noise irritates you and the fact that you're a Christian.  Please edit that noise out of your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know what, I'm not an active user here, but I know the answer since it's the same as at Islam.SE where I'm more familiar.

> I WAS VERY OFFENDED AND I FLAGGED IT AS UNFRIENDLY OR UNKIND.

This is the correct action, and it looks like it's already led to deletion.  If someone posts something super-offensive, ***enough flags will trigger automatic deletion***, even without a diamond moderator lifting a finger (i.e., self-moderation): *The system will automatically delete any post flagged six times as offensive or spam* ([meta.SE reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/351283)).

But the all-caps is not the cause of the offensiveness.  (cf. CHRISTIANITY IS GREAT.)  However, it's likely there's a correlation between ALL-CAPS posts and low quality; and there's a correlation between low-quality posts and offensiveness.

> THIS SITE IS FOR VERY RELIGIOUS CHRISTIANS.

As I understand, this is untrue (here and at all the religious Stack Exchange sites).  The relevant meta post is: [Brothers, we are not Christians‼](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians)  This has long been a pillar of how to define religious Stack Exchange sites, which was pioneered here.

I think it's more accurate to say that ***it's for people who want to learn about Christianity***.  Unsurprisingly, most people who are interested in learning about Christianity happen to be Christian.  But nevertheless, there are not "Christianity tests" to participate; instead there's the [Code of Conduct](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Anyone can join in and immediately participate, even though this allows idiots to post horrible things.  Every single Stack Exchange site has this problem.

> ANY "NOISE" WILL RUIN THIS WHOLE SITE AND IS VERY IRRITATING ME.

I disagree with the first claim: the site is far more stable than that, and it's not going to fall apart at the first sign of rowdiness.  The second claim, that it's very irritating, is probably widely accepted.

> CAN WE PLEASE BLOCK ANY QUESTIONS/ANSWERS/COMMENTS HERE THAT ARE WRITTEN IN ALL CAPS?

This makes the post *a feature request*, and up/down-voting will reflect the community's opinion.  I note that diamond moderators here are incapable of implementing this feature request.  I also note that Stack Exchange are very careful with feature requests: they often take years to implement, with development and testing.

I think it's not necessary.  Why:

- Off the top of my head, I would guess that 90%+ of all ALL-CAPS posts are worthy of deletion.  The users are helping you identify their rubbish by writing in ALL CAPS.  **Ah, all caps.  Don't need to waste my time reading that.**

  Now, if they're blocked from using ALL-CAPS, they'll simple make the minimum number of edits required to be able to post the same rubbish.
- For the ALL-CAPS posts worth salvaging, there's an "edit" button, which I believe anyone can use.  Those with lower reputation have their edits reviewed before they're officially made.