# I am stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

Eight years. All the way from [September 2011](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/532/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) to today, I never once imagined that I would be writing this resignation notice. I can hardly believe that I *am* writing this now.

Through the whole absolute *train wreck* of a fiasco that was SE forcibly stripping Monica Cellio of her diamonds and then effectively slandering her publicly, among quite a number of other injustices, I firmly believed that once the whole situation had been resolved one way or another, then SE would learn their mistake and make an effort not to repeat it again. I was *pissed*, to be sure, but I still had a modicum of hope.

This morning... *sigh* ... [Shog9 and Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stackexchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with-t) were fired. Much like Monica too, in fact - suddenly and with no warning whatsoever. Shog and Robert were two of the *the* most respected and admired Community Managers, and both have worked for SE for 9+ years. In particular, I've respected and admired Shog from day 1 and I have always found his advice to be *immensely* valuable. I hold him in high esteem as both a manager and a person.

That Shog could be fired was literally unthinkable for me. The possibility never once crossed my mind, even for a fraction of a second. For SE to do this and *simultaneously* claim that they're doing this to ensure the community has "a seat at the table" (yes, [really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342045/214929)!) indicates to me that the higher ups at SE are 100% out of touch with the community. There is *zero* sense in pursuing better community engagement by firing the two people most responsible for the fact that said community *is* highly engaged. Shog and Robert were *indispensable* when it came to starting communities such as this very one and keeping them together despite myriads of issues that threatened to rip them apart.

I bow to you, Shog9 and Robert Cartaino - thank you so much for your service.

I bow to you, good people of Christianity.SE - it was a great honor to serve.

I have found StackExchange the company to be unwelcoming, unrepentant, and deaf, so I will [shake the dust off my feet](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+6:11&version=NIV).

---

P.S.: I can be reached at my Gmail - `lee314b` or on Discord as `El'endiaStarman#8918`. I will probably also continue to hang out in a few SE chat rooms, so you might find me if you look hard enough.

Comment: I'm very sad to see you go, but understand completely.

Comment: Hats off to you, El'endia.

Answer (score 25):

I'm sorry it came to this; but given that SE the company really has become completely *deaf* to the things that matter to the very communities they fostered [I understand](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/30) why you have to step down. Having worked with you behind the scenes I know that you served this site and its community well, and with [the likes of Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/145951) you can hang up your hat in good company.

Answer (score 15):

My response:

Thank you for all your hard work and dedication through the years. You were a significant reason, one of many, that this website was such a joy to participate in. I can hardly believe how self-destructive the company is being.

Company response (probably):

While it is unfortunate that moderators have been uncooperative with the direction of this thriving site, we are grateful to the ones who have left for not making us chase them out the door. Also, they probably did unsavory things but let's just leave it at the level of insinuation. We cannot comment further (especially not to acknowledge their years of community-building and sacrifice) at this time.

Comment: Company response ([actually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342045/271431)). You didn't miss the mark by much.

Comment: @reirab That's pretty much what I was satirizing, along with their initial response to community inquiries about Monica's departure.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. From the "probably" it sounded like you hadn't read their response yet. At any rate, you pretty much got it right on.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry to hear that it has come to this El'endia Starman. As far as I am concerned you will always carry that ♦ amongst us, just like Caleb and Nathaniel did.

Ever since Monica has been forced to leave and drop her ♦ I have been sure this this whole affair has not been finished.

My only hope now is that your diamonds ♦️ may be turned into a genuine resurrection stone of your new status, whatever that may be.

May God Bless you and all who are dear to you and may your sorrows be turned into joy, by the Author of all Hope!

You are truly missed.

All three of you are in my prayers.

Answer (score 4):

A house without its foundation will surely fall.

Your long service is appreciated.  Your touch will be missed.

As we say around here: *vaya con Dios, amigo*.