# Fond memories of former members or those on an extended leave of absence?

Tags: discussion

**Fond memories of former members or those on an extended leave of absence?**

Would anyone like to recall some fond memories of any former members or moderators, I would like to hear your story (stories), for those who do not mind sharing.

People have come and gone for a variety of reasons, including the one we all must eventually one day must face. Here I am thinking of [Affable Geek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1039/affable-geek), who passed away in 2015.

Some have left for other
[reasons](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6815/i-am-stepping-down-as-moderator) and I totally respect that!

I do not want to make this a long post, so I leave the floor to those who wish to share their stories!

Answer (score 2):

Moderators have a very delicate job to do here and no one is perfect, including myself.

Some years ago I got into a heated debate in the comments with another user. Caleb had a few words with me about what to do and not to do with making comments.

Like a true mentor, he directed me how to always remain cool and charitable with others.He clearly saw that I was getting frustrated.

Thank you, Caleb!

Comment: @caleb.     Caleb was the best moderator